# Get Last Post instagram of public_users

Tags: php, html, api, instagram

I have a site written with PHP. I asked if it would be possible to automatically display the latest public post on Instagram on my site? And who will open the site to see the posts? No need to enter the Instagram account

If it is possible, please give me guidance so that I will look for its training

Example :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library:

> https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Example call:

1. Installation:

   ```
   $ composer require cosenary/instagram
   ```
2. Initialize the class:

   ```
   use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;

   $instagram = new Instagram(array(
       'apiKey'      => 'YOUR_APP_KEY',
       'apiSecret'   => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
       'apiCallback' => 'YOUR_APP_CALLBACK'
   ));

   echo "<a href='{$instagram->getLoginUrl()}'>Login with Instagram</a>";
   ```
3. Data:

   ```
   $result = $instagram->getUserMedia();
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to pull an instagram feed with PHP without logging in?

Comment: how can use from https://www.instapi.io/u/appwithus ?????????? 
how can echo last image and caption from json of https://www.instapi.io/u/appwithus.  ?????